# Rails4: Use .include? and LIKE in an array query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an array:

```
@available_languages = ["English", "German", "Japanese"]
```

and a variable:

```
@needed_language = "Basic English"
```

I want to show 'Available!' in the view if a @needed_language is present in the @available_languages array, even if the names don't match exactly, such as 'English' and 'Basic English'

Right now, my conditional only returns true for exact matches. How do I return true for non-exact matches?

```
- if @available_languages.map{|a| a.available_language_name}.include? @needed_language.needed_language_name
  Available!
- else
  Not Available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use select function, something like this:

```
@available_languages = ["English", "German", "Japanese"]
@needed_language = "Basic English"
if @needed_language.split(" ").select{ |a| a if @available_languages.include? a} then 
  "Available" 
else 
  "Not Available" 
endif
```